# dojo deferred with a for loop

Tags: asynchronous, for-loop, dojo, deferred

I'm having trouble processing a dojo deferred in a for loop.  I'm working through this now, but any insight from someone higher would really help, this has been a multi day affair.  It seems that Dojo deferred can only be resolved once, which causes it to crap out in a for loop. Whats the best way to handle multiple responses asynchronously.

Here's my snippet, there's no globals some variables are declared outside of this snippet.

**edit: Dojo has a .then() which is supposed to handle async requests. Does this look right to anyone, when using the 'then()' i can see the calls start but they never show as completed.  do I need to add a c 'deferred.callback' after the then? **

```
for (var j = 0; j < ident.length; j++) {
            if(ident[j].url != "http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Canvas/World_Light_Gray_Reference/MapServer"){
                deferred = ident[j].execute(idParams);
            }
            deferred.*then*(function(response){
                return dojo.map(response, function(result){
                    var feature = result.feature;
                    feature.attributes.layerName = result.layerName;
                    //console.log(feature.attributes);
                    lyrIdent.push(feature.attributes);
                    var template = new esri.InfoTemplate("Prefix: ${PREFIX} <br/>Suffix: ${SUFFIX}<br/>Divcode: ${DIVCODE}<br/> lmp: ${LMP} <br/>hmp: ${HMP}");
                    feature.setInfoTemplate(template);
                    return feature;
                });
            });
        }
```

Comment: Could you add some context about what you are trying to do?  Are you trying to make multiple async calls and waiting until all of them have returned?  What error are you seeing in the console?

Comment: @BuffaloBuffalo yes I'm making multiple async calls.  The calls are being made and data is being returned, I can see the "lyrIdent" array being filled with data but the dojo deferred object returns nothing, in reading up ono the dojo deferred object it seems that it only handles a single object in an array synchronously vs multiple objects in an array asynchronously

Answer (score 3):

Right now you have a single variable for the deferred object. If you want to make multiple async calls then you need to create multiple Deferred objects, one for each call (if you put them all together, how would you know when each of the different calls is done?)

```
var deferreds = [];
for(var i=0; i<N; i++){
    deferreds[i] = your_async_request();
}
```

Once you have your list of promises, you should be able to use the [all function](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/promise/all.html) (or something similar) to take that list of promises and turn it into a single promise that gives back a list of results when they are all done.

```
require(["dojo/promise/all"], function(all){

  all([promise1, promise2]).then(function(results){
    // results will be an Array
  });

});
```

Comment: thanks, I'm using the ESRI library which is built on top of dojo and they are a few iterations back.  I'm going to mess about with the all usage.  Also the calls are created in loop and these functions are called in order in the loop so they are less async and more ordered.  I failed to clarify this in the post.  Thanks for the comment, I'll work through it a bit

Comment: @atlMapper: If you want to run things in parallel but all is not available there is a similar function in the older Dojo versions but I forgot the name (IIRC, its on the Deferred library and the only problem is that the API is a bit uglyer). On the other hand, if you want to run the requests sequentially you need to rewrite your code to use recursion instead of a for loop.